# Set eth0 as DHCP in raspberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi3, dhcp

I want to set eth0 of RPI (Raspbian Stretch) to be DHCP, my goal is that when I will connect any device that communicates using TCP/IP protocol, that device will receive an IP address.

I have found many guides that all lead to making eth0 ip address static, which is not my intention.

Currently a device is connected through eth0 , `ifconfig` says it has some IP but pinging the hostname of the device gets no reply. wlan0 is connected via wifi.

Here is some info :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.31.197  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::ad5a:8219:4c27:b59b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:f3:f2:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 81  bytes 26568 (25.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46  bytes 10544 (10.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 31  bytes 3472 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31  bytes 3472 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.71  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fd01::60ff:8818:5965:dc58  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::473d:110e:5474:8000  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:a6:a7:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 955  bytes 74427 (72.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 184  bytes 22096 (21.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Any advice to how to achieve my goal will be happily received.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to connect two devices (without routing/forwarding/etc), i.e. for a standalone test network, this should work:

1. Figure out what IP range you want to use, and what IP you want your
   DHCP server to have (let's call it **IP_DHCP**)
2. Install *isc-dhcp server*
3. Set static IP address for eth0 (e.g. set it to the **IP_DHCP** you
   chose earlier)
4. Configure */etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf* for the desired network range (*man
   dhcpd* has a decent reference), make it authoritative (unless there
   are other DHCP servers).
5. Run *service isc-dhcpd-server start*

Example of a configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
sudo nano /etc/conf/dhcpd.conf
```

Uncomment *#authoritative* to make it authoritative

Add along the following lines(customize based on what you decided in step 1), where *routers* is **IP_DHCP**:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.100;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
}
```

Save buffer and close

```
sudo service isc-dhcpd-server start
```

Good luck!

P.S. if you are getting *connect:network not found* issues, then you likely have an issue in your routing tables (*route*) setup.

Something along the lines of

`sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.1`

where the IP address is your eth0 will likely allow communication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Using_DHCP_to_automatically_configure_the_interface
i.e. just add this to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

if you're really pedantic you could create a file like /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0-dhcp and paste these lines into it - the end result will be the same.

Comment: Hi,
I have tried that - all it did is remove completely all interfaces

Comment: The question is about dhcp server on eth0

Answer (score -1):

NetWork Manager (nmcli) might be running on the device and has been configured to work with a static IP.

The following commands can help you check if your device is managed by nmcli:

## nmcli d

## nmcli con show

Run the following command and replace 'Wired connection 1' with the name of your connection.

## nmcli con show 'Wired connection 1' | grep 'ipv4.method'

ipv4.method will show "auto" if set to DHCP or "manual" if set to static.

http://www.intellamech.com/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi_nmcli.html

Comment: Hi, it is not managed by nmcli.

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nmcli d
bash: nmcli: command not found`